# How can i save the image into my directory from url?

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

Here is my code which i am trying to save image in my directory and the image coming from stamps.com server which is shipping label.

The issue is here the image url, so how can i save image in my directory from this image url ? Please suggest me ?

```
<?php

$image_link = "https://swsim.stamps.com/Label/label.ashx/label-200.png?AQAAAKAUuNCk4tIIR-Wcnzg_AVv9iN6G78nuM772Yl14nLVR3ysEURQ-d1nDKj8i5W0QD0rdOzM7ZuZtbMvsYmhn2SgxfmT9mJ3sLuKFFxIvHj14QEr-AY9Sm7zw4sWzP0B5Q8p1Z23Spjz5OnVO95zvu_d8F89oUNOkHa9oD5vhA-rOt09WGjULw6tn5x1a3149veMS12NVWBYsjLEqBRVJImWmm3bsxRbGrYu6STuV4vmYnbFT9po9azuUlsei_bzlLq7UBiVVZr1scjq97PAJew0o5fRUds6dSvpCup8pioQG8qlDkRVSwkSruiKWoffxZnhoUDfDlAIX0-NGQh8BVupmPDIQMr7ZpexhGIBykih4QREg-GrBLfyED9C4HzE58PapsPaBN9nxKwcv6yIKLaHCXCmbBEUGIIJI0jfvjRenO1PXrU1H29GNp7I9n6y-HQY--jXByPpyonOyddn9PIEgL-DPrGbmnAZVwpgQoqhqUBYllll0ErgaVbYf78sLeQf-QqCEyJ0ACP4FCKGCtudhsNisouEfdVue3JzblQScNzq3-_vC1UPWoMXHY3qoN2L28C0eDcD7Y1oMqAAkfN1E4ROAypAZ";//Direct link to image
$split_image = pathinfo($image_link);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $image_link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$response= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$file_name = "images-folder/".$split_image['filename'].".".$split_image['extension'];
$file = fopen($file_name , 'w') or die("X_x");
fwrite($file, $response);
fclose($file);
```

And the error i got :

```
Warning: fopen(images-folder/label-200.png?AQAAAKAUuNCk4tIIR-Wcnzg_AVv9iN6G78nuM772Yl14nLVR3ysEURQ-d1nDKj8i5W0QD0rdOzM7ZuZtbMvsYmhn2SgxfmT9mJ3sLuKFFxIvHj14QEr-AY9Sm7zw4sWzP0B5Q8p1Z23Spjz5OnVO95zvu_d8F89oUNOkHa9oD5vhA-rOt09WGjULw6tn5x1a3149veMS12NVWBYsjLEqBRVJImWmm3bsxRbGrYu6STuV4vmYnbFT9po9azuUlsei_bzlLq7UBiVVZr1scjq97PAJew0o5fRUds6dSvpCup8pioQG8qlDkRVSwkSruiKWoffxZnhoUDfDlAIX0-NGQh8BVupmPDIQMr7ZpexhGIBykih4QREg-GrBLfyED9C4HzE58PapsPaBN9nxKwcv6yIKLaHCXCmbBEUGIIJI0jfvjRenO1PXrU1H29GNp7I9n6y-HQY--jXByPpyonOyddn9PIEgL-DPrGbmnAZVwpgQoqhqUBYllll0ErgaVbYf78sLeQf-QqCEyJ0ACP4FCKGCtudhsNisouEfdVue3JzblQScNzq3-_vC1UPWoMXHY3qoN2L28C0eDcD7Y1oMqAAkfN1E4ROAypAZ): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\upwork\test.php on line 13
X_x
```

Comment: Do you have errors? When does your script start to fail and how?

Comment: Yes i updated my question with errors.

Comment: @LajosArpad any way to do ?

Comment: Are you sure there is an images-folder in the directory you are in?

Comment: Yes i have created that, and the i checked for save image to different url and it is working perfect. Only this url is not !

Comment: check the permissions of the folder.

Answer (score -1):

`<?php
$url = 'http://example.com/image.php';
$img = '/my/folder/flower.gif';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));`

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\upwork\test.php on line 17